The proof that the real zeta has the same domain as the complex valued zeta
I’m reading Havil’s book, Gamma. In Appendix E on p. 249 he has a proof that the complex valued zeta function has the same domain as the real valued zeta function.
He basically shows that $\zeta(x) = \zeta(\text{Re}(s))$.
I have two questions: (1) Can you help me fill the gaps in the proof? (2) Does $\zeta(x) = \zeta(\text{Re}(s))$ need a proof? It seems obvious.
This is his proof:
$$
\begin{align}
    \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{r^z}\right | &= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{e^{z\cdot\ln r}}\right |\\\\
    &= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{e^{\left [ \text{Re}(z) + i \text{Im}(z)\right ] \ln r}}\right |\\\\
    &= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1} { e^{ \text{Re}(z) \ln r} \cdot e^{i  \text{Im}(z) \ln r}}\right |\\\\
    &= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1} { e^{ \text{Re}(z) \ln r}}\right |\\\\
    &= \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} { r^{ \text{Re}(z)}}
\end{align}
$$
Are the bars to indicate absolute value? If so why do we need to work with absolute values?
Eqn (1): I know about the identity $e^{\ln x} = x$. How do we derive $x^a = e^{a\ln x}$ ?
Eqn. (3): How did he eliminate $e^{i \text{Im}(z) \ln r}$ ? Eqn.(4) does not have this term.
Eqn. (4) How did he eliminate the bars? The last equation does not have the bars.
We know that the real valued zeta is valid only for $x>1$. We want to show that the complex valued function also has the same domain.
Instead of going through these steps in order to eliminate the imaginary part by algebra why can’t we just write $\zeta(x) = \zeta(\text{Re}(s))$ ?
If this is true then the domain of a complex function is independent of the imaginary part? Why is this so? And is there a theorem to that effect?

Havil is not showing that the complex zeta function has the same domain as the real one. Instead, he is showing that the real function can be continued to the complex domain. The proof shows the conditions under the complex zeta function defined by the famous series converges.

$\displaystyle x^a = e^{a\log(x)}$. This is the definition of $x^a$ when $x,a\in \mathbb{C}$. Check page 101 here.
He eliminates $e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r)}$ given that:

$$ e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r)} = \cos(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))+i\sin(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))$$
So
$$ |e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r)}| = \sqrt{\cos^2(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))+\sin^2(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))} = 1$$

The bars are eliminated given that $e^{x}>0 \; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}\;$. In the proof $\ e^{\operatorname{Re}(z)\ln(r)}>0$ given that $\operatorname{Re}(z)\ln(r)\in \mathbb{R}$

So again, Havil is showing that the real zeta function defined as a series can be analytically continued to the complex domain and the complex function is valid for $\left\{z\in \mathbb{C}|\operatorname{Re}(z)>1\right\}$

Thanks for the answer. This was helpful. But there is one thing I noticed. If I understand correctly, Havil is not saying that the function is valid in $\left{z\in \mathbb{C}|\operatorname{Re}(z)>0\right}$, he is saying $\left{z\in \mathbb{C}|\operatorname{Re}(z)>1\right}$. See his Figure E.2.

@zeynel you’re right. It was a typo, fixed now.

Before I accept your answer can you fill in the steps about how you get the $cos^2+sin^2$  term inside the square root? And do we need the i before $sin^2$?  Thanks again.

@zeynel That step was due to the Euler's formula. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula  and some proofs here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula

I still don’t see it. Euler’s formula is $e^{ix} = cos(x) + i\sin(x)$. This is your first expression. How do you obtain the second expression?

@zeynel When $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$ then the modulus (the analogous of the absolute value for complex numbers) is defined by
$$ |z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers

I don't know why you are refusing to fill in the missing steps. $e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r)}$ is not $|z|$. And you don't have  the square root of $x^2 + y^2$ but the trig identity inside the square root. So not clear how you get the last step. Thanks anyway, I'll ask somewhere else.

Hi, I'm not refusing to fill them. I never said that $e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r)}$ is $|z|$. I said that for any $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z=x+iy \quad x,y\in \mathbb{R} $ then $ |z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.
Since
$$\underbrace{e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r)}}{z} = \underbrace{\cos(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))}{x} + i \underbrace{\sin(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))}_{y}$$
Then
$$|e^{i\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r)}| =\sqrt{\cos^2(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))+  \sin^2(\operatorname{Im}(z)\ln(r))}=1 $$
This is still not clear? Feel free to ask anyone, the answer will be the same

Thanks for the help. It's all clear now.
